# Hard links linux, memory

Tags: linux, memory

When you copy files in linux(using contex menu copy command) does linux create hard links of files ?
Also, what happens if you delete original file, than hard link, that file still persist in memory, but it's pointer is removed ?
I have trouble understanding few things with a memory.
To free disk space, you need to delete both files, right ?
Does hard link points to memory location of a original file ? I used to see term inode, I'm now quiet sure what inode really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inode is all the file data except the content.

A directory contains a set of names and numbers: "This directory contains file foo, which is file number 3 on this drive, bar, which is file number 4, quux, 17, viz, 123 and lastly ohmygod, 77321341". Inode number 3 contains "This file was created on Januar 1, 1970, last modified on January 1, 1990 and last read on January 2, 1990. It is 722 bytes large, and those bytes are in 4k block number 768123 on the drive" and a few more things.

The stat() system call shows how many blocks are needed, and almost everything else related to the inode.

Comment: That depends on the programming language. If you just want to play around, try perl for this, perl is a fine choice for small hacks. man perlfunc, search for stat.

Comment: how to call it from a terminal ? :D

Answer (score 0):

Copying does not create hard links, that would be broken behavior. A hard link is just an additional first-class name to the same file; modify the file via one name (and not by saving under a temp name and then moving it, as some editors do), and you will see the change in the file when accessed under the other name, too. Not what I’d expect from a copy.

Note that there is nothing special about the first name a file had. All hard links are simply pointing at the same file.

Once the last directory entry pointing to a file is removed, there may still be file handles open pointing to it (from programs that opened the file). As long as one of those exists, the file is still there and can be used. It just cannot be opened by processes that haven’t done so before any longer, since it has no name any more.

When there is no more directory entry pointing to a file and no program has an open handle to the file any more, it can never be reached again. Therefore, the operating system frees the space on the disk.

Comment: You told me everything I already knew :/
How to see how much space particular file consumes ?
When i copy files and use ll -h command it always says 4K

Comment: You asked “does A do B?” and my answer starts with “no, A does not do B.” If you already knew that, why did you ask? Small files will always take a full block on most file systems, and that seems to be 4k on your computer.

Comment: Also, you are talking about “deleting both files,” where there is only one file, with two directory entries pointing to it. Seems you should re-read what I wrote.

Comment: I wanted to check am I right, and thought that somebody will explain it more thoroughly. Can you answer me on this: How to see how much space particular file consumes ?
When I copy files, it always says that they consume 4kb(Files larger than 4kb)

Comment: You also did not mentioned what inode is :)

Comment: I don’t have a linux at hand to check – `ls -h` usually works fine for me, but you can also use `du -sh`. For what an inode is, I’m not going to copy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode – and your question still doesn't make sense if you knew what I wrote, there is no “deleting both files” and the files aren’t stored in memory in the first place, unless you have a memfs.